# CodeIgniter loads the only default controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am really stuck with this problem

in CodeIgniter i have controller named user.php

and it has two function getUser() and save()

when I try to call `http://localhost/CodeIginter/index.php/user/save`

it always call getUser function why ?

```
class user extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function getUser()
    {
        $this->load->model('usermodel');
        $data['query'] = $this->usermodel->get_last_ten_entries();
        $this->load->view('users',$data);
    }

    function save()
    {
        $this->load->model('usermodel');
        $this->usermodel->insert_entry();
        $this->load->view('users');
    }
}
```

my .htaccess file contain

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

and i am also unable to load another controller that is helloworld.php

Comment: Maybe you have wrong routes at your codeigntiter project. Can you please copy your routes.php file content?

Comment: $route['default_controller'] = "user";
$route['404_override'] = '';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be 2 problems:

**1. Missing route** :

Goto **application/routes.php**

```
$route['user'] = "user";
```

2.You need to make function public if you want to call it from outside in url.

So,

```
class user extends CI_Controller
{
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

public function getUser()
{
    $this->load->model('usermodel');
    $data['query'] = $this->usermodel->get_last_ten_entries();
    $this->load->view('users',$data);
}

public function save()
{
    $this->load->model('usermodel');
    $this->usermodel->insert_entry();
    $this->load->view('users');
}
}
```

Hope your problem is solved now:)

Comment: You don't need to write a route for every controller as it beats the purpose of CI. And methods are considered public by default.

Answer (score 2):

step-1: change this `.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /your_folder_name/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

step-2: `application/config/config.php`

```
$config['base_url'] = 'full_path';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

step-3: `application/config/routes.php`

```
$route['default_controller'] = "user";
```

step-4: user class add this function

```
public function index(){
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Controller names must be capitalized. So, `User` instead of `user`.

```
class User extends CI_Controller
class Helloworld extends CI_Controller
...
```

The file names remain in lowercase though.

Other than that, everything seems fine.

Answer (score 0):

Goto application/config/routes.php

Answer (score -3):

It seems you are missing a route. Add the following line to your `routes.php` file

```
$route['user'] = "user";
```

And now it should be working as expected

Comment: You don't need to write a route for every controller as it beats the purpose of CI.